# What does @TestFor do in a unit test for a domain?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-domain-class

When writing a unit test for some class in Grails 3, I can use the `@TestFor` annotation to specify the class I want to test. In my unit test I then have a field "controller" if my class under test is a controller and a field "service" if I am testing a service, and I can use these fields as the "system under test".

I am wondering what `@TestFor` is doing in a test for a domain class and how it is supposed to be used. I couldn't find any documentation that deals with this case. Let's say I have a domain "MyDomain" and a test "MyDomainSpec" that starts like this:

```
@TestFor(MyDomain)
class MyDomainSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        def doesntMatter = domain // just to check access to "domain"
```

The last line already gives me a

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'class MyDomain' with class 'java.lang.Class' to class 'MyDomain'

which probably means that Grails tries to use an object that represents the MyDomain class as an instance of this class. I wonder why this is happening and what's wrong with the code? I mean, the `domain`property exists, and it does for a reason, or doesn't it? How can I use a property that throws an exception when merely accessing it?

**Update**
Apparently the exception is thrown only if the domain class has a field `String name`in it. I have no clue what should be so special about this field. Could it simply be a bug?

Comment: This seems like a useful article. They use `@TestFor` on a domain class http://www.christianoestreich.com/2012/11/domain-constraints-grails-spock-updated/

Comment: @zero01alpha This is an interesting read by itself, thank you. But regarding TestFor they only mention that it makes the method "mockForConstraintsTests" available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@TestFor` annotation does a number of things for a Grails domain class, but most importantly it mocks the behavior and GORM functionality of the domain and provides a getter that returns an instance of the domain class.

Domain classes are registered as prototyped Spring beans, so the getter just asks the application context for a new instance and then sets that instance into a private `$domain` field which is returned on subsequent calls to the getter. Note that your `def doesntMatter = domain` is using this generated getter and is equivalent to `def doesntMatter = getDomain()` where `getDomain()` returns a new instance of `MyDomain`.

It sounds like your assumptions are correct. Invoking the getter should not cause an exception. The following works fine:

```
@TestFor(MyDomain)
class MyDomainSpec extends Specification {

    void "a new domain can be saved"() {
        given: "a new instance of MyDomain"
        def d = domain // or getDomain()

        expect:
        d.id == null

        when:
        d.save()

        then:
        d.id != null
    }
}

@Entity
class MyDomain {

}
```

**EDIT:**
This was related to a bug in Grails and should be fixed in the next release, see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10363.

Comment: Thank you! Your code works for me, too. Are you sure about "the getter just asks the application context for a new instance every time it's requested"? My debugger tells me otherwise - I get the same instance for consecutive usages of domain or getDomain. Concerning the CastException: apparently it happens when MyDomain has a field "String name" in it. Strange...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The getter only asks for a new instance from the application context if the private `$domain` field is not null. So you will get the same instance unless you explicitly set `$domain = null`.

Comment: Ok I do see the `GroovyCastException` with the `String name` too. I'll try to figure out why.

Comment: This was a bug in Grails and should be fixed in the next release, see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10363#issuecomment-268129552